# This workbook cannot be opened because it is not stored in a trusted location. to create a trusted location, contact your system administrator

Tags: excel, web-applications, sharepoint-2013, powerpivot

I use `SharePoint 2013` and i have a BI Web Site.

I change my web site name inside `DNS Server` but after this change my `PowerPivot Report` can not open.

I get this error :

```
This workbook cannot be opened  
because it is not stored in a trusted location.  

to create a trusted location, 
contact your system administrator.
```

[image]

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be easily fixed. You need to create a trust location for your document library.

Please refer this- 
http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.com/2011/12/this-workbook-cannot-be-opened-because.html

As the link said: 
How to add a file to trusted file location:

1. On the Start menu, click All Programs.
2. Point to Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products, and then click SharePoint 2010 Central Administration.
3. On the SharePoint 2010 Central Administration page, under Application Management, click Manage service applications.
4. On the Manage Service Application page, click Excel Services Application.
5. On the Manage Excel Services Application page, click Trusted File Locations.
6. On the Excel Services Application Trusted File Locations page, click Add Trusted File Location.
7. On the Excel Services Application Add Trusted File Location page, in the Address text box, type the location to save your workbook
8. Under Location type, click the appropriate location type. In this example, select SharePoint Foundation.
9. Under Trust Children, select Children trusted if you want to trust child libraries or directories.
10. Click OK.